# Not able to access generic type in a component

Tags: typescript, typeerror, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I'm new to typescript. I am not able to figure out why I am not able to access this generic type in my component?

```
type frameworkType = {
  value: string;
  label: string;
};
```

This is how I am using my component:

```
<FancyMultiSelect<frameworkType> values={FRAMEWORKS} className="w-[300px]" onChange={onChange} />
```

Glimpse of my FanceMultiSelect Component:

```
export const FancyMultiSelect = <T,>({ values, className, onChange }: IFancySelectProps<T>) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<T[]>([]);
  const handleUnselect = (option: T) => {
    setSelected((prev) => prev.filter((s) => s.value !== option.value));
  };

 {selected.map((option) => {
            return (
              <Badge key={option.value} variant="secondary">
                {option.label}
            )
         }
     }
```

It just throws error like: `Property 'value' & 'label' does not exist on type 'T'.ts(2339)`

Help me out!

I tried creating my own type in FancyMultiSelect component. But that doesn't make any sense? Or is it the only possible way out?

Comment: What if the generic type is something else? You don't know that it has a `value` or `label` property. Or you do you want to constrain it?

Comment: @Unmitigated Um, I am passing 'frameworkType' as a generic type to component. That has value and label properties. Shouldn't I be able to use it then? Or it's not possible that way? I am sorry, I am kinda new to this.

Comment: But you could have passed another type too (e.g. `{}`). You can only access properties that would exist on any possible type that can be  substituted for the generic type. So, does the `value` field exist on every possible type that `T` could be?

Comment: Okay, Now I am getting an idea. I feel the only possible way out is to define same type in 'FancyMultiSelect' component? Or is there anything else?

Comment: I don't see how generics help in this case. Could you explain why you're using it?

Comment: I was just trying new things for practice. Since, you said it wouldn't work in this case. I will try it in another example. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `So, does the value field exist on every possible type that T could be?`

Yes, I guess – That's the case in my situation. `value` and `label` will exist in every possible T.

Comment: Then you must explicitly constrain it, e.g. `<T extends frameworkType>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly [constrain the generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) so that it always has certain properties. In this case, you could replace `<T>` with:

```
<T extends frameworkType>
```